# Double fetch to the nodejs server with undefined originalUrl

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm fetching a request to a nodeJS backend to query data from sql express server via the mssql library.  I make 2 requests to the server via fetch, first the users then the groups inside the THEN clause of the first promise and it works fine.

The problem is that when the THEN clause is executed the nodeJS backend receives a new request ( a third one ) with the req.originalURL with the value /undefined.

How can I avoid this third call to nodeJS ?

```
function readGroups(){        
    const comando=`/grupos?id=1`
    var grupos=fetch(comando);      // generates a request.  
                                    // and nodeJS sends data back. Thats Ok

    grupos.then(datos=>{   // But when I press F11 here it generates a new 
                           // request to nodeJS with the req.originalURL 
                           // with the value : /undefined 

         return datos.json().then(data=>{return data;});
    }).then(datosJson=>{
        crearListaGrupos(datosJson); 
    })
}


// Server side
app.get("*",(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.originalUrl);   // it's /undefined
});
```

Comment: whenever I see code like `.then(data=>{return data;})` I suspect the person doesn't know promises very well :p

Comment: Yeah, the structure of your promises is off. I'd review promises and pay close attention to how the reject and resolve callbacks work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises